# Redirect all urls except a few

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect all urls in my website except few .Please see the examples below.

```
domain.com
domain.com/forum
domain.com/commnuity/123
```

I have lots of urls like that i want to redirect all the urls to domain.com/us except domain.com/account/payments.

I need main domain also need to redirect to domain.com/us

I have tried lots of code from internet but none works.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect all urls except **/account/payments/** ,you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^((?!account/payments).*)$ /us/ [L,R]
```

if there are more then one uris to exclude, just tweak the pattern like this **^((?!uri1|uri2|uri3).*)$**